# Storing uploaded file in state variable wont work. React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, file, upload, state

I am trying to store an uploaded file in a state variable that I will post to the DB once the user has completed the rest of the form. For some reason, my state wont update and my state variable is left null. I am calling onChange and passing it my onChange function to store the file in state. I put some comments in the code. Can anyone help please?

```
interface PostState {
  file: File
  //i have tried multiple data types for the file variable, still no luck
}

const Form = (props) => {

  const defaultPostState: PostState = {
    file: null,
    //i have also tried setting this to undefined or not setting a default value at all as well
  }

const [postState, setPostState] = useState(defaultPostState)

const onChange = (e) => {
  setPostState({...postState, file: e.target.files[0]})
  //this is what wont work - i have debugged it and logged it, it wont store the target file in file
}

<div className='form-group'>
  <label>Upload file</label>
  <input
    id='file'
    className='form-control-file'
    type='file'
    name='file'
    ref={register}
    onChange={onChange} 
  />
</div>
```

Comment: where did you put `console.log` in your code?

Comment: I logged it right after trying to store it 
const onChange = (e) => {
  setPostState({...postState, file: e.target.files[0]})
  console.log(postState.file)
}

Comment: `useState` is asynchronous, so you have to wait for the next rendering to get the updated state. Use `useEffect` to log it. `useEffect(() => console.log(postState.file), [postState]);`

Comment: Logging it is not the issue, Storing it is. It wont store in the postState.file variable.

Comment: As I said, `useState` is asynchronous, try logging it in `useEffect`. Then if the problem is still there, we will continue.

Comment: My hunch is that either `e.target.files[0]` never has the File value that you're expecting it to have, or you're expecting `postState.file` to have your value immediately after the `setPostState` call (which won't work because `useState` isn't synchronous like @TríPhan says).

Comment: @TríPhan I know that the variable is not storing because when I was debugging my post function which is called when the form is submitted which  I didnt include in the snippet of code I could see that the poststate.file is still null. I will try what you are doing in a moment

Comment: @ReedDunkle e.target.files[0] has the file because I logged it previously. I will try the UseEffect.

Comment: @TríPhan UseEffect logged the uploaded file properly. Where do we go next?

Comment: Then handle your uploaded file in the `useEffect`.

Comment: @TríPhan Do you mean you want me to setPostState in useEffect? I am trying to store the file somewhere so I can post it with the rest of the form all at once

Comment: No, I don't mean that. Actually you can use `FormData` to get input data from the form, so you don't have to store the file in React component state.

Comment: @TríPhan ill try it out

Comment: @TríPhan Do you have any examples of how to use FormData in typescript? I can't seem to find any.

Comment: Here is an example https://gist.github.com/Mysbeario/254a601ef3d6c41ed7243a8613c6e129. The function will be passed to `onSubmit` action.